# How to replace statefulset with deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, sts

We have an sts, say as below for example -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: test-app-onkar
spec:
  serviceName: test-app-onkar
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app-onkar
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test-app-onkar
      labels:
        app: test-app-onkar
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app-onkar
        image: 10.1.1.100:5000/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
```

We use helm and our charts have above sts definition. Now we have **REPLACED** the above file with a deployment.yaml as shown below and done a `helm upgrade` operation using our new charts.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-app-onkar
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app-onkar
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test-app-onkar
      labels:
        app: test-app-onkar
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app-onkar
        image: 10.1.1.100:5000/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
```

All's well as the helm upgrade creates a new deployment **test-app-onkar**. But the sts **test-app-onkar** is still not removed. It is still there and i think that is the expecation? If so, how to ensure that kubernetes actually removes the older sts and creates only the new deployment. What possible ways can this be achieved?

Comment: Is `values.yaml` used? Are there any references to the sts/deploy? Is it the same file with different context within? See [how it's done for ingress nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L181-L183), you can select whether it's deploy or daemonset. And there's a check in `template`. See [daemonset template](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-daemonset.yaml#L1).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor No, i had to let it go. I can bring up the new deployment but not delete the sts by way of charts only. There were some annotations and stuff that kinda suggested that there was a trick to get helm to do that, but we tried out and it did not. Matter of fact is on some machines it is actually completely replacing the sts with the deployment, the very same charts package.. whereas on some other instances it just brings up the deployment leaving the sts as it is.

Comment: @moonkotte ya, we use values.yaml.. the issue is that we have sts already and we wanna do a helm upgrade now to a charts package that has a new deployment that is to replace an exsiting sts.